# How long does it take to render a 10 sec long YouTube intro in Blender?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I just want to know!
Please help!

[image: This is my render right now]

Comment: It could be 1 second or 100 hours, it depends on... Well, everything you could use in 3D software and also hardware used for rendering.

Answer (score 2):

Rendering time depend on a multitude of factors: the scene's complexity, image size, the speed of the computer's CPU and number of cores, available RAM, etc, etc.

If you look on the top of the render window  you'll see how long it took to render one frame.

[image]

Multiply that number by the number of frames that you want, and you should get a rough estimate of how long the whole thing will take to render.